# How to give hyperlink instead of values in interactive report of Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

There is a interactive report which I have created using ORACLE APEX. The source for that interactive report is the sql query output, given by me.

The generated SQL output have one column, which is having integer values. Now my requirement is to use this integer value(lets say "11111", these integer values are variable values) and a link ("www.xyz.com/", this is a fixed string) and generate a concat value of these two string, it will create a hyperlink ("www.xyz.com/11111"), so this link I want to use as hyperlink for the integer values in my report.

Answer (score 5):

Define your column as a Link, then substitute the values you need within the declaration

[image]

The same #COLUMN_ALIAS# substitution syntax can be used fro your Link Text, or if you just want to dynamically generate the url from SQL using `apex_page.get_url`

Alternatively, you can formulate whatever you like in the HTML Expression attribute, using the same syntax

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

Steps are as follows:

- Change the type of your column to "Link" which you want to have as link.
- Go to Link subsection for that column --> Choose type as "URL" --> In URL section give "www.xyz.com/##"
- This will create that as hyperlink, for example "www.xyz.com/11111".

Comment: Ahh, now I understand your requirement a little better. Wouldn't your URL be ww.xyz.com/#MY_ID_COL# ?

Comment: Yes Scott, for each row value the link should have the row value substituted in the end. With the method I used, I am able to get this result.